# React Native Large List V3

Tags: react-native

can anyone tell me is there any version boundation with this library. I am using it with React-native version 0.69.0. But when i try to sync it it gives me error

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by "version boundary"? What are you trying to integrate this library with? What API version do you expect to have compaitibility with? If it follows semver, then just go by what you should be able to safely assume according to semver.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is not an issue to the larger list. you are missing some dependency . please install the following decency and the versions I specified with npx or yarn

```
yarn add react-native-largelist-v3@3.1.0-rc.1  react-native-spring-scrollview@3.0.2
```

or use this command

```
npx install react-native-largelist-v3@3.1.0-rc.1  react-native-spring-scrollview@3.0.2
```

Please remember that only these version are compatible other are not compatible.Please ready [this](https://bolan9999.github.io/react-native-largelist/#/en/V3/GettingStart)

```
 "react-native-largelist-v3": "^3.1.0-rc.1",
 "react-native-spring-scrollview": "^3.0.2",
```

Comment: they're using gradle though :/ How is a yarn answer applicable in this case?

Comment: @starball they are using react-native and for react-native-largelist-v3 you have to install react-native-spring-scrollview . please read this https://bolan9999.github.io/react-native-largelist/#/en/V3/GettingStart

Comment: hey @Engr.Aftab Ufaq   bolan9999.github.io/react-native-largelist/#/en/V3/GettingStart
 i follow this one i faced this error. but i don't find any solution

Comment: is it work without sync it in android studio

Comment: @seemaGoyat please install the version I have specified  and it then run this command npx react-native run-android

Comment: @seemaGoyat yes it work without sync. actually. you didn't install react-native-spring-scrollview so that why this dependency is missing

Comment: @Engr.AftabUfaq please check this when I can hide data then it's space also hide but my output is like that when I hide a data but data space is not hide How can hide the data space here output https://imgur.com/a/eq31iir

Comment: to hide a contact or data you need to to Crete a temp_second array and delete that from that. or if you want. to hide that when you have to remove its height from the  heightForIndexPath={() => moderateScale(49)} on this based on the index.

Comment: @Engr.AftabUfaq https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75105632/how-to-set-custom-heightforindexpath-in-react-native-larglist please check this question

Comment: I was also looking for this and now I found an answer. heightForIndexPath={() => 'auto'}